# Export data from Hbase to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, export, hbase

I want to export hbase table data from hbase to hadoop as .txt file so that I can using other tools to import the .txt file to SQL Server. I tried`hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export test /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/test`
It only gave me a file folder not a txt file.

Anyone can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo "scan 'Employee',{COLUMNS=>'EmployeeInfo:Name'}" | hbase shell | grep "^ " > EmplyeeExport.txt

This command might be helpful to you.... in above Employee is a table and EmployeeInfo is column family.

Comment: This give me a .txt file which contains the result of the hbase scan result, but I can't use it to import back to MS sql server. Is there any other way so that the txt file can be import to MS sql server?

Comment: Ok. One approach that i can suggest here is that create a table in hive and connect with hbase table. And now i believe you should be able to import hive data into MS sql server,